# Suggest a way to update time every minute

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

I have a full ajax application. i am using the below code to update time every minute. But if i keep the browser open for >10 min the browser becomes non responsive/slow. Suggest a better code.

```
function tick()
{
    var d = new Date();
    var time = padNumber(d.getHours(),2)+':'+padNumber(d.getMinutes(),2);
    $('#WeatherBoLfTime').html('&nbsp;'+time);
    t = setInterval('tick()',60000);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    tick();
})
```

Comment: See http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#other.timeouts , specifically "Hidden use of `eval`"

Comment: If you only rely on a setTimeout, your code will break when the user puts his computer to sleep and then turns it back on later. See below; you'll need more than a setTimeout!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `setInterval` many times and never clearing any of them.  So after a while you have lots of interval callbacks running at around the same time.

Change

```
t = setInterval('tick()',60000);
```

to

```
t = setTimeout(tick,60000);
```

When I first started out coding JavaScript I took down a Lycos web server with AJAX calls because I made the same mistake :-)

Note that since you're displaying the actual time, you should use a much shorter timer than 1 minute.  If I land on your webpage at 13:42:30, the time will not be updated until ~13:43:30. To keep it in sync with the machine's time, you would probably want to set the timer for `1000`.

Comment: This will result in the timer only running once.

Comment: @Johan: no, because it's a recursive timer call.  Please read the code properly.

Comment: That'll break when the user puts his computer to sleep and then turns it back on. See below.

Comment: @frenchie: the OP didn't ask to keep time synched with the server.  Stack Overflow seems to be full of people failing to read properly today.  Please retract your down vote.

Comment: @AndyE: the idea is not to keep the page in synch with the server but rather in synch with itself by using the server as a fixed reference point.

Comment: @frenchie: if that were the case, updating the time on a separate interval would not make any sense - it would just be updated every time the AJAX call returns.  I think you're reading far too much into it.

Comment: @frenchie: the idea is to update a bit of HTML on the page to show the time (in hours and minutes) that is obtained from `New Date()` There is no syncing involved, it is just displaying the current date from the local computer...

Answer (score 3):

`setInterval()` sets an interval. You only need to set it up once, it will get called every 60000ms automatically. `setTimeout()` is the one you have to setup every time again.

Comment: That'll break when the user puts his computer to sleep and then turns it back on. See below.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, you are creating new interval every time.
Move it to outside your function.

```
function tick()
{
    var d = new Date();
    var time = padNumber(d.getHours(),2)+':'+padNumber(d.getMinutes(),2);
    $('#WeatherBoLfTime').html('&nbsp;'+time);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    t = setInterval(tick,60000);
})
```

Edit: I'm slow and other answers seem to be updated. So this one is useless now :)

Comment: That'll break when the user puts his computer to sleep and then turns it back on later. See below.

Comment: @frenchie: unless the setInterval actually stops running entirely (which would mess up all methods) then this will work. The time will be out of date for potentially up to a minute until tick runs again but when it does the time will be correctly set (since its getting the time each time it displays, not just incrementing what is already there).

Comment: @frenchie: There was no mention that it has to work when client goes to sleep. And my answer works for the given question. Like all others. There was no need for downvote..

Answer (score 0):

Have look in below demo code, which will be updated each second...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>j</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">

   function myFunction() 
   {
       setInterval(function(){ 
            var d = new Date(); 
            document.getElementById("dates").innerHTML = new Date(d.getTime());}, 1000);
   }
   
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="button" name="e" onclick="myFunction()">
 <p id= "dates">ok</p>
</body>
</html>
```